# How to keep a downspout extension from coming off?

Tags: downspout, extension

Had to replace a downspout because it was stepped on.  I replaced it with a downspout extension, which is longer and does a better job of letting the rain water drain away from the house.

The only issue I'm facing is if we have a heavy rain or high winds, the downspout extension comes off, thus defeats its purpose.

Is their anyway to keep this extension on when experiencing heavy rain and winds?

(can't upload a pic because its too big)

thanks

Comment: White sheet metal screw through the overlapped sections.  Or if you want to get fancy, a pop-rivet.

Comment: If you can't figure out how to resize your photo, use words. The question is too broad otherwise.

Comment: @SteveSh  Type your comment up as an answer.

Answer (score 3):

White sheet metal screw through the overlapped sections. Or if you want to get fancy, a pop-rivet (converted from my comment).

Note to Jack - some of the other SE sites seem to discourage 1 (or 2)-sentence answers.  I have been asked on at least one occasion to convert an answer into a comment.

Comment: Simple answers for simple problems are fine! +1

Comment: This site is a bit more friendly and understanding than many others.

Comment: If one or two sentences actually answers the OP's question, they're fine.+ – JACK 22